# Solving Quadratic Equation By Using Mathematica

Tags: mathematica

I was bothered with the following very simple problem:

> Solving a quadratic equation $x^2+x+1=0$ in mathematica

if I use "solve" function in mathematica as below:

**Solve[x^2 + x + 1 == 0, x]**

I will get very weird solutions

$$x = -(-1)^{1/3}; \;\;\; x = (-1)^{2/3}.$$

However, instead of using $\;$**Solve[x^2 + x + 1 == 0, x]**,  I use

**Solve[a * x^2 + b * x + c == 0, x]**

and then substituting back $a=b=c=1$, then I can get the correct roots (which I expect to see...); i.e., I obtain
$$
x_{1,2} = \frac{-1 \pm i\sqrt{3}}{2}.
$$

It seems to me I get different solutions which really bothers me alot. Did I miss anything? or can anyone help to explain why this situation could happen? By the way, my mathematica version is 10.3.0.0

Comment: Use the following:  `Solve[x^2+x+1==0,x]//ExpToTrig`.

Comment: @thanasisdr, Wow Amazing!! it works.. Thank you so much!! But I still don't quite understand why the exponential-form looks so weird..

Comment: @Fianra You are welcome!